# PrintWriter not writing to file.[Java]

Tags: java, arrays, object, file-io, outputstream

I have a problem with this code for homework. Whenever I run it, the console does not display anything, I am able to write anything I want, but the script does not terminate on its own, as if it was on an infinite loop. What's more, the output file does not write either. I am currently learning about the input and output streams, so I do not know really what else I could do to fix this. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public class PublicationListingProcess1 extends Publication implements Serializable{
static Publication PublicationArray[];
static String a, n, line;
static int y, c = 0, p, count = 0;
static long z;
static double s;

enum PublicationTypes{PUBLICATIONCODE, PUBLICATIONNAME, PUBLICATIONYEAR, PUBLICATIONAUTHORNAME, PUBLICATIONCOST, PUBLICATIONNBPAGES}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        File f = new File("PublicationData_Input.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            c++;
        }
        PublicationArray = new Publication[c];

    System.out.println("Welcome to this organizing software.");
    System.out.print("Please enter the destiny file for output: ");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    File outFile = new File (kb.next()+".txt");
    FileWriter output = new FileWriter (outFile);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter (output);

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String [] split = input.nextLine().split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        {
            z = Long.parseLong(split[0]);
            n = split[1];
            y = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
            a = split[3];
            s = Double.parseDouble(split[4]);
            p = Integer.parseInt(split[5]);
            PublicationArray[count] = new Publication(z, n, a, y, s, p);
            writer.println(PublicationArray[count]);
            count++;
        }

    }
output.close();
input.close();
    }

    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You are never closing the `PrintWriter`

Comment: you are reading in a blank text file.. your program has nothing to parse

Comment: try passing in a text file with 1 or 2 sample lines to see what, if any, errors you get

Comment: The file on its own it's a file provided by the teacher, which is read in the console:                                                                             900876512 Core_Java 2007 Mike_Simon 129.99 568
765867999 Java_Applications_for_Programmers 2010 David_Wilson_and_Jack_Westman 173.25 672
465979798 From_Java_to_C++ 2008 Linda_Jackson 118.73 439
760098908 Microsoft_VC++ 2006 Garry_Wesley 165.20 416
529086890 Software_Engineering 2005 Alain_Macmillan 219.99 651
765867999 Visual_Basic 2004 Mary_Rosen 108.33 388
But it is not transferred at all

Comment: I also added the following lines: input.close();
 output.flush();
 output.close(); but it still does not write anything into the file. Thanks for answering by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problematic code:

```
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        c++;
    }
```

`Scanner.hasNextLine()` does *not* move the pointer forward. So if your file contains something, you have an infinite loop.

To solve this infinite loop, simply remove this while block. It does nothing with appearent meaning , at least in the posted code. Remove the `while` block, and change the PublicationArray fron an array into an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
import java.util.*;

public class PublicationListingProcess1 extends Publication implements Serializable{
    static ArrayList<Publication> pubs;
    static String a, n, line;
    static int y, p, count = 0;
    static long z;
    static double s;

    enum PublicationTypes{
        PUBLICATIONCODE, 
        PUBLICATIONNAME, 
        PUBLICATIONYEAR, 
        PUBLICATIONAUTHORNAME, 
        PUBLICATIONCOST, 
        PUBLICATIONNBPAGES;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
               File f = new File("PublicationData_Input.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

               pubs = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("Welcome to this organizing software.");
            System.out.print("Please enter the destiny file for output: ");
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

            File outFile = new File(kb.next()+".txt");
            FileWriter output = new FileWriter(outFile);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] split = input.nextLine().split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    z = Long.parseLong(split[0]);
                    n = split[1];
                    y = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                    a = split[3];
                    s = Double.parseDouble(split[4]);
                    p = Integer.parseInt(split[5]);
                    pubs.add(new Publication(z, n, a, y, s, p));
                    writer.println(pubs.get(count);
                    count++;
                }

            }
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The example code above preserved your main control flow, but there may be better way around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I used that while loop to count how many lines there are in the document since I have to input each line as information into the PublicationArray object.

Comment: I actually discovered the problem. What happened is that I assumed the pointer reset itself. Now I opened the stream twice since I know reopening a stream is impossible. Now it does work, what I am trying to figure out now is how to write the object to file. Thanks for the answer. Didn't think about the array list, thanks for the feedback!